# How to test a change on observable in service mock?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, observable

I have to test a backend service stub, which returns an observable.
The stub method:

```
public postStatus(handle: string): Observable<StatusReturn>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.result = {
        currentlyProcessedFileName: 'datei2.pdf',
        errParams: [],
        numFiles: 3,
        numFilesAlreadyProcessed: 1,
        numTasksBefore: 0,
        processingStatus: 1,
        technicalRetCode: 0
      };
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.result = {
        currentlyProcessedFileName: '',
        errParams: [],
        numFiles: 3,
        numFilesAlreadyProcessed: 3,
        numTasksBefore: -1,
        processingStatus: 2,
        technicalRetCode: 0
      };
    }, 10000);
    return of(this.result);
  }
```

Additional info: result is initialized on Service level, so setTimeout just updates these params.

I've tried a lot, but my 'closest' approach is the following:

```
fit('postStatus should return changeing Observable<StatusReturn> with correct second sample data after 5000ms', fakeAsync(() => {
    // WHEN
    const secondReturn = {
      currentlyProcessedFileName: 'datei2.pdf',
      errParams: [],
      numFiles: 3,
      numFilesAlreadyProcessed: 1,
      numTasksBefore: 0,
      processingStatus: 1,
      technicalRetCode: 0
    };
    let result;

    // DO
    service.postStatus('handle').subscribe((res) => {
      result = res;
    });
    tick(5001);

    expect(result).toEqual(secondReturn);
  }));
```

The test gives the following errors:

```
Expected $.currentlyProcessedFileName = '' to equal 'datei2.pdf'.
Expected $.numFilesAlreadyProcessed = 0 to equal 1.
Expected $.numTasksBefore = 1 to equal 0.
Expected $.processingStatus = 0 to equal 1.
```

where left side is initial data (so I get data from observable) and

```
Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.
```

which indicates that the first data update is fired. I was able to approve this by changing `tick(5001)` to `tick(4999)` and have two timers in queue.

I am looking for suggestions on how to update the result variable with the new observable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your function is doing something other than what you are wanting.
We can test that by adding some console.log statements.

```
service.postStatus('handle').subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('setting return');
    result = res;
});
console.log(`result is ${result}`);

tick(5001);
console.log('tick 5001 occurred');
```

> LOG: 'setting return'
>
> LOG: 'result is undefined'
>
> LOG: 'tick 5001 occurred'

This tells us that your subscribe returned instantly, as that is the first console log we see. Since the timer hasn't yet fired the result is undefined.

Since you're returning an observable and expecting it to have two different results, I'd like to suggest a slightly different approach for your method under test. We can return a `Subject<StatusReturn>` as follows.

```
public postStatus(handle: string): Observable<StatusReturn> {
    const currentStatus = new Subject<StatusReturn>();

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.result = {
            currentlyProcessedFileName: 'datei2.pdf',
            errParams: [],
            numFiles: 3,
            numFilesAlreadyProcessed: 1,
            numTasksBefore: 0,
            processingStatus: 1,
            technicalRetCode: 0
        };
        currentStatus.next(this.result);
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.result = {
            currentlyProcessedFileName: '',
            errParams: [],
            numFiles: 3,
            numFilesAlreadyProcessed: 3,
            numTasksBefore: -1,
            processingStatus: 2,
            technicalRetCode: 0
        };
        currentStatus.next(this.result);
    }, 10000);
    return currentStatus;
}
```

Notice that I'm calling `currentStatus.next(this.result)` to tell the subject that the result has changed?

With this in place you can slightly alter your test to look like

```
fit('postStatus should return changing Observable<StatusReturn> with correct second sample data after 5000ms', fakeAsync(() => {
    // WHEN
    const secondReturn = {
        currentlyProcessedFileName: 'datei2.pdf',
        errParams: [],
        numFiles: 3,
        numFilesAlreadyProcessed: 1,
        numTasksBefore: 0,
        processingStatus: 1,
        technicalRetCode: 0
    };
    let result;

    // DO
    service.postStatus('handle').subscribe((res) => {
        result = res;
    });

    tick(5001);
    const firstResult = result;

    expect(result).toEqual(secondReturn);

    tick(5001); // clear the queue
    expect(result).not.toEqual(firstResult);
}));
```